# create a folder based on textbox and save as excel sheet inside this foder C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm creating a folder and an excel file every time I run my routine and its has been working just fine.
But i cannot find a way to save this excel file inside my this specific folder I just created.

I would like to create my folder and save my excel file inside it, of course my folder name will be different every time.

Any ideas for this?

What I have tried:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\temp\\" + foldername.Text);
sheet.SaveAs("c:\\Temp\\" + excelname.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: The line `Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\temp\" + foldername.Text);` will fail in compilation. The “\” characters in the string are going to cause problems. You either need to add a `@` character before the string like… `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\temp\" + foldername.Text);` OR add an additional “\” character before each existing “\” character like…`Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\temp\\" + foldername.Text);` The same idea applies to the "SaveAs" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following way would probably work:

```
string foldername = foldername.Text;
string myDir = @"c:\temp";
string dirPath = Path.Combine(myDir, foldername);
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);

sheet.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dirPath, excelname.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: Hello Sh.Imran, Thanks a lot, your solution worked pretty well for me, I do appreciate it.

Comment: @nsilva Welcome. Its my pleasure that your problem is solved. Mark the answer as `Accepted` and upvote as well. It is appreciation gesture here at StackOverflow :).

Comment: @nsilva Kindly upvote it also, by click on up-arrow above the tick mark.